# Cmake failing at linking step of sample program

Tags: c, cmake, msys2, ninja

I have been searching for an answer to my problem for a while now and I haven't found any useful information yet. I'm hoping someone here can help me out. I'm trying to get CMake working on a Windows 10 machine through MSYS2 and it's proving to be a difficult job for me to say the least, lol.

I've managed to figure out how to install msys2 and then install the build toolchain and get it running in the correct environment so I get some sort of output, but now I'm stuck at a step in the Ninja build process and I can't get past it...

Here is the pertinent section of the error log:

> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_d5d92.exe
>
> FAILED: cmTC_d5d92.exe
>
> cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cc.exe   CMakeFiles/cmTC_d5d92.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -o cmTC_d5d92.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_d5d92.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

And I can't figure out what path it cannot find. All of the .obj, .a, etc files with the "cmTC_*" are temporary because they change every time I run this command, so I can't really check to see if any of those are invalid, but I don't think they would be. I've checked the .exe file in the command and it exists on my system... So I don't know where to go from here. I'd imagine that permissions or configuration might be the issue, but I don't know where to look, or what to check next.

BTW: this is the command I am running:
 `cmake -G Ninja ..`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you did? What MSYS2 packages did you install? How does the CMakeLists.txt look like? What does the code look like?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sure. After installing Msys2 I installed the "mingw-w64-x86_64-" versions of each of the following: gcc, ninja, cmake, and "toolchain" (which includes gcc and several other packages that I thought might be needed).  I'm also running the MINGW64 environment of msys2.  That's it as far as configuration goes, the command I execute is "cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release.

The project I'm trying to build is libgit2 v1.4.4